# Bypassing Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

Assuming there is more than one ethernet NIC as well as a wireless device on a given system, how can I specify custom settings in `/etc/network/interface` for one of the NICs but allow Network Manager to manage the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Manager ignores NICs mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces` by default. So don't add anything about the other NICs in that file. From [`man NetworkManager.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html):

```
[ifupdown]
   This section contains ifupdown-specific options and thus only has effect 
   when using ifupdown plugin.

   managed=false | true
          Controls  whether  interfaces  listed in the 'interfaces' file are 
          managed by NetworkManager.  If set to true, then interfaces listed in 
          /etc/network/interfaces are managed by NetworkManager.  If set to 
          false, then any interface listed in /etc/network/interfaces will be 
          ignored by NetworkManager. Remember that NetworkManager controls the 
          default route, so because the interface is ignored, NetworkManager may 
          assign the  default  route to some other interface. When the option is 
          missing, false value is taken as default.
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just issued `nmcli dev status` and it turns out the desired NIC isn't being managed.